# Use ResultSet object in JSP without JSTL

Tags: model-view-controller, jsp, servlets, resultset

I want to pass my query's result i.e ResultSet to JSP just for the display as i am using MVC framework.

My Servlet Code:

```
Connection c=Connectivity.dbConnect();
       PreparedStatement ps=c.prepareStatement("select role from login where userid=? and password=?");
       ps.setString(1,userid);
       ps.setString(2,pass);
       ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();

     if(rs.next())
     {

          if(rs.getString(1).equals("admin"))
                   {

           ps=c.prepareStatement("select * from user where userid=?");
           ps.setString(1,userid);
           rs=ps.executeQuery();   
           Result r=ResultSupport.toResult(rs);          
           request.setAttribute("res",r);       

           rs.close();
           c.close();
           return mapping.findForward("us");//to User.jsp


                   }
      }
```

I've used ResultSupport.toResult() to forward it to JSP (forwarded by 'us' mapping) but that requires JSTL code in JSP :

User.jsp -

```
<c:forEach var="data" items="${requestScope.res.rows}">
      <h1>${data.userid}</h1>
               <h2>${data.name}</h2>
               <h2>${data.password}</h2>
               <h2>${data.emailid}</h2>
  </c:forEach>
```

Moreover if i directly pass ResultSet like `request.setAttribute("ResultSet",rs);`  i wouldn't be able to close the connection in JSP.

This Code works fine but i do NOT want to use JSTL/EL or Lists , i want to use scriplets in JSP that can handle Result or ResultSet attribute from Servlet.

Comment: Why. Why would you want to do that. "As I am using MVC framework?" But you just want to skip the M? Booooooo.

Comment: Why, is it not possible to transfer the view part of the table to JSP and use simple scriplets ??

Comment: Sure, it's somewhat possible--it's just a horrible idea, on multiple levels. Scriptlets are bad. Keeping a ResultSet open for the duration of JSP rendering is bad. Result I *guess* is at least better; don't know why you can't use a result in a scriptlet. Also don't know why you'd *want* to, but that's a different issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can overcome your issue like this:

1) In your database manipulation class use a POJO to add in results from ResultSet.

```
Contacts myContact = new Contacts();
myContact.setOffice(rs.getString("office1"));
myContact.setMail(rs.getString("xx@xx.com"));
```

2) Then use a List to store your results

```
List<Contacts> myList = new ArrayList<Contacts>();
myList.add(myContact);
```

3) Pass the list to your request/session Object and close ResultSet/Connection there

```
request.setAttribute("LIST",myList);
rs.close(); 
conn.close()
```

4) In JSP get the List and iterate over it anyway you want

```
ArrayList<Contacts> myList = (ArrayList<Contacts>) request.getAttribute("LIST");
for(Contacts obj: myList){
  out.print(obj.getMail());
  ....
  ....
}
```